# Debugin UDI program by gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

The program from below asks user for his name, greetings him and then gives us his real ID. We could assume that in case of 16-letter name (or longer) the uid variable will be overwritten and the program gives us incorrect user ID. But it isn't. How to explain this by using `gdb`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct user_info
{
    uid_t uid;
    char name[16];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct user_info info;
    info.uid = getuid();

    printf("Your name: ");
    scanf("%s", info.name);
    printf("Hello, %s!\nYour UID id %d.\n", info.name, (int) info.uid);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your struct like this

```
struct user_info
{
    char name[16];
    uid_t uid;
};
```

It will override as your expect.